# How javascript handles multiple requests being Singlethreaded?

Tags: javascript

How javascript handles multiple requests being Single threaded? Please explain in detail

Comment: [Concurrency model and the event loop - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Comment: You order a coffee to a cashier. The cashier pushes the coffee machine's button. While the coffee is being poured, you pay the cashier. Then you get your coffee. The cashier is single-threaded, but can manage to do several things at once. That's how Node.js works.